# Android not able to read and write data using Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to send data basically text between two devices with Sockets in which one will be acting as **ServerSocket**.I am able to connect the devices but I am not able to read data from inputstream this is my code(Same for both server and client );

Code For writing data:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                    text = message.getText().toString();                                               
                    out.println(text);
                   update(text);


             }
         });
```

Code for reading data from inputstream:

```
 //Finding problems in this code! Not Recieving exceptions but not able to make toast too.
  try{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        while (( clientMsg=in.readLine())!=null){


   update(clientMsg);

        }
        in.close();
        socket.close();
        update("Connection Closed");
    }catch (IOException e){
        update(e.toString());
    }
```

Update Method:

```
  public void update(final String msg){
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(activity,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

I am not abele to get the Toast when the device recievs some data in it's OutPutStream . Can I know whats wrong with my code??

**Edited**:**Entire MessageReader class(Used for reading and writng data from sockets)**

```
 public class MessageReader extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private View view;
    private Activity activity;
    EditText message;
    Button send;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    private TextView textView;
    private String text;
    public MessageReader(Socket client, View root){
        socket = client;;
     this.view = root;

         activity = (Activity)root.getContext();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String clientMsg;
update("Now in MessageReader");
          message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.yourMessage);
             send = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
             textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);

             send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   update("about to send message");
                  text = message.getText().toString();



                         out.println(text);
                         update(text);


                 }
             });


        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            update("waiting for a message");
            while (( clientMsg=in.readLine())!=null){
                update(clientMsg);
                updateUi(clientMsg);

            }
            in.close();
            socket.close();
            update("Connection Closed");
        }catch (IOException e){
            update(e.toString());
        }




    }

    public void update(final String msg){
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(activity,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
    public void updateUi(final String message){

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(message);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you maybe post the entire code which is used to read the data? Specially the things before the catch block would be helpful

Comment: The problem is the part where you are reading the data. You are doing this only once. And if there is no data in the stream it will not be printed. You should do it with an Service which is running in background and always listening on the socket. As there is a message this service should tell this UI to display that message

Comment: Well i am using a while loop to read that data. which will read till the input is not null.So i dont think thats the problem

Comment: If you are creating the socket and there is no input on the socket it will never go inside the while loop

Comment: I just tried and i am able to read the data as many times you write to the outputstream but i am not able to write the data

Comment: in.readLine() this method will wait till it recives a input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112411/discussion-between-zeusnet-and-jois).

Comment: ThankYou i found the solution it was printwriter's constructor had to specify autoflush true :D

Comment: Ah ok :D nice job :) But I'm not quite sure that the readLine method will wait for input. I had a look in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Comment: Try with program use Scanner or bufferedReader to read the input. They will wait till you enter something

Comment: You are right :D Learned something new today, thank you :D

Comment: Your welcome do you mind for a upvote